# custom option image URL

Tags: custom-options

I am in need to display custom image uploaded by user into the cart page. I have a custom image with label 'image'.

The file is uploaded in RootDirectory/media/custom_images.

Can you please help me with the method to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default magento is not providing this functionality for that you need to override file

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

```
<dl class="item-options">
    <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
    <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $this->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
    <?php if($_option['option_type'] == 'file'):?>
        <?php // override here as per your requirements?>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
```